# Is it ok to put a bend in the gas supply to a boiler?

Tags: natural-gas

I am replacing the natural gas valve on my Utica MGB-100HD boiler. Currently, the gas valve goes directly into the pipe that feeds the burners, and the valve sticks out awkwardly, encroaching on the washing machine. It has been bumped more than once, which makes me nervous.

When I replace the valve, I would like to add a 90° piece of pipe to rotate the gas valve to be more beside the boiler, out of the way of the washing machine. Is there any potential problem to adding a bend in the natural gas supply to the boiler?

I have attached a crude drawing to help clarify.

[image: current and proposed diagram]

Comment: Unless you already have a large number of bends in the line from the meter, one more is unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: Is this "gas valve" the shutoff valve, or the appliance combination gas control valve?

Comment: It is the valve for the boiler. The thermocouple and the pilot supply tube both plug in to it.

Comment: If this is a manual shut off valve you are moving  it would be okay to move it as shown in your depiction.